# magento 2.4 multiple modules override the same block class

Tags: magento2.4, preference

I have the following situation:

- third party module A overrides core block php class via preference in order to customize a method
- the original method gets the input, loops it to extract  some data, then returns a new  array with these data
- the overridden method first checks if some backend flag is true. If it is, it falls back to the core method (`return parent::coreMethod()`), otherwise gets  the same input, loops it to add the core info plus new info, then returns the new array.

I need to do some stuff inside the foreach but here I am stuck on how to proceed: I know the best way is via plugins but I tend to avoid Around plugins and use preferences instead. In this case, I cannot use a preference because a preference for this core class already exists. To summarize:

- Before or After plugin don't suit my case
- Around plugin should be the right way but it is very expensive
- My preference for core class gets ignored because a preference already exists
- Creating a preference for the custom block class instead of the core class would allow my preference to work but it doesn't suit this case because it would stop working if I disable the custom module.

So my question is:

for this particular case, is there an alternative to the around plugin?

Comment: I can see your tough situation, but I think the Around plugin is the last option. If you go with preference, you need to cover both the logic, the 3rd party module's functionality, and your custom stuff. So no worries about the Around plugin, I have also used it in such tough situations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see I have no choice. Although plugins are one of the things I most love about magento 2 I dislike the around plugin a lot. Anyway, if there is no another choice, I'd  better use it